# Eliminating the Default DataFrame column while reading Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scrapy

I need to read an excel file which has below data:

[image]

But when i read it using `pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx')`

I also get the 1st default column which Pandas adds itself.

I have used the options like - `index_cols=0 , index=0, index=False, index_cols=None`

But it has no effects.

Can you please help me get rid of this first default column ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow. At least describe what you are doing, and why the answers to the mentioned question do not fit you.

Comment: Sure. I have a scrapy crawler, which scrapes and downloads the PDFs from a website based on a date range. I need to create a unit test for the same. To check if all the data has been scraped for all the dates in the given date-range and downloaded or not.

Comment: You should update your question. And you should explain why none of the many solutions from that other StackOverflow question work for your use case.

Comment: can't understand what is a fake HTML response, neither the example is explained. That's why i cant interpret the solutions